# Accessing dynamic variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `$.each` in which I have category IDs like `103` or `104` that are set with `cat_id`.

Now, inside that function, i want to run another `$.each` to access an array which has items that are sorted by those category IDs, like:

```
$.each( data.menu_items.items_CATID, function( key, val ) {

                    $.each( val, function( key2, val2 ) {
                        htm3+=''+val2.item_name+'..';
                    });


});
```

So basically, I need to access `data.menu_items.items_103` or `data.menu_items.items_104`.

How do I set the variable? I tried with:

`data.menu_items.items_'+cat_id+'`

and such but that doesn't work.

The data is basically an array like:

```
menu_items:
items_251: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
items_252: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: We really need to see some more code,

Comment: Can you include the data in `data.menu_items` in your question, so we can see what you're working on?

Comment: @SimonBrahan Will do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
data.menu_items['items_' + cat_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what you need but, have you tried :

```
const itemId = `items_${catId}`
data.menu_items[itemId]
```

I hope this helps !